# how to get sum with whereIn/whereBetween using laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have getting wrong value from query. can anyone help me to correct my query in laravel project.
mysql code :

```
select SUM(amount) as total from `sales` 
where `bankid` = 1 
and `month` = 8 
and `year` = 2020
and userid in (select userid from user where bank_id=2 AND (usertype=1 OR usertype=2))
```

Laravel code :

```
function test($bank_id,$usertype,$month=NULL,$year=NULL){
    $query = Sales::query();
    if(is_numeric($bank_id)){
        $query->where('bankid',$bank_id);
    }
    if($month)
    $query = $query->where('month', $month);
    
    if($year)
    $query = $query->where('year', $year);

    $query = $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"));
    if(is_numeric($usertype)){
        $query->whereIn('userid',function ($query) use($bank_id,$usertype) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('userid'))
            ->from('user');            
            if(is_numeric($bank_id)){
                $query->where('bank_id',$bank_id);
            }                 
            if($usertype==1){
               // $query->whereBetween('usertype', [1, 2]);
                $query->where('usertype', 1);
                $query->orWhere('usertype', 2);
            } else {
                $query->where('usertype',$usertype);
            }
        });
    } 
    return $query->get()->toarray()[0]['total'];
}
```

When i used querylog and got the query:

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog(); 
dd($query->toSql(), $query->getBindings());

select SUM(amount) as total from `slaes` 
where `bankid` = 1 
and `month` = 8 
and `year` = 2020 
and `userid` in (select userid from `user` where `bank_id` = 1 and `usertype` =1 OR `usertype` = 2)
```

I need to make it from `and userid in (select userid from user where bank_id = 1 and usertype =1 OR usertype = 2)` to `and userid in (select userid from user where bank_id = 1 and (usertype =1 OR usertype = 2))`

And can anyone suggest to minimize loading issue while running this query. i have almost 1M records in my database.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get your expression inside brackets in Laravel ORM you need to use callback function inside `where` like this:

```
$query->where(function($query) {
  return $query
    ->where('usertype', 1)
    ->orWhere('usertype', 2);
});
```

But in your case you can also use shortest method:

```
$query->whereIn('usertype', [1,2]);
```

Comment: i have try with $query->whereIn('usertype', [1,2]); also. but It is also taking much time to return response.